# UITextField: right view accessibility (voiceOver)

Tags: ios, uitextfield, accessibility, voiceover

I'm adding two UIButton to the right view of a UITextField, but voiceOver can't see them (it "reads" only the containing view). I already set right view's accessibilityElementsHidden to 'no'. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

EDIT: I'm subclassing UITextField, can be related to this?

Comment: It's a UITextField property: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/rightView

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
// MARK: - VoiceOver handling
extension MyTextField {
    public var voiceOverElements: [UIAccessibilityElement] {
        guard UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning else {
            return []
        }
        let element: UIAccessibilityElement = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: self)
        let rect: CGRect = UIAccessibility.convertToScreenCoordinates(frame, in: self)
        element.accessibilityFrame = rect
        var result: [UIAccessibilityElement] = subviews.filter { $0 is UIButton }
            .map {
                let element: UIAccessibilityElement = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: self)
                let rect: CGRect = UIAccessibility.convertToScreenCoordinates($0.frame, in: self)
                element.accessibilityFrame = rect
                return element
            }
        result.insert(element, at: 0)
        return result
    }

    public override class func isAccessibilityElement() -> Bool {
        false
    }

    public override func accessibilityElement(at index: Int) -> Any? {
        voiceOverElements[index]
    }

    public override func accessibilityElementCount() -> Int {
        voiceOverElements.count
    }

    public override func index(ofAccessibilityElement element: Any) -> Int {
        guard let element = element as? UIAccessibilityElement,
              let toRet = voiceOverElements.firstIndex(of: element) else {
            return 0
        }
        return toRet
    }
}
```

You should override UIAccessibleContainer methods in order get subviews accessible frames. In this case I am getting only buttons but you can omit that.